# Neglect multiple records in SQL Server based on condition and produce result

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have the following table in SQL Server:

```
consult_date patient_id consultation_cost
-----------------------------------------
2021-10-30    1           -10
2021-05-30    1            10
2021-02-08    1            20
2021-01-27    1            22
```

I want to select latest consult_date for the patient 1 and generate reminders. Here the latest consult_date is 2021-10-30 but the problem is consultation has been cancelled since consultation cost is negative here.

I want to neglect this record as well as neglect the consult_date 2021-05-30 as well since the consultation_cost (10) is similar to negative consultation cost (-10) which has been cancelled.
So the latest consult date should be 2021-02-08 .

Solution should be find the maximum consultation date. If cost is positive then take that as maximum consultation date. If it is negative then neglect that record and neglect the similar cost in positive value for the same patient record and take the next maximum consultation date.

Comment: What's wrong with `TOP (1)` with an `ORDER BY` to get the "top" row??

Comment: In what way are the first two consults similar? They're five months apart. You need to define rigorous logic / business rules, else we're just guessing.

Comment: I want to find the maximum consultation date , if the consultation cost is negative then i want to neglect the negative cost record and similar positive cost record as well and get the next maximum consultation_date

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUM over partition by [patient_id] in descending order by [consult_date] and then find the maximum date with a positive value.

```
Select patient_id, Max(consult_date) As consult_date
From (
Select consult_date, patient_id, SUM(consultation_cost) Over (Partition by patient_id Order by consult_date Desc) As Agg
From Tbl) As T
Where Agg>0
Group by patient_id
```

Output:

```
patient_id  consult_date
----------- ------------
1           2021-02-08
```

Comment: I like this idea. We don't know whether it's possible to have the newest rows with values -10, 5, 5 or -10, 5, 15 and how to deal with such cases, but your solutions seems even appropriate for such special scenarios.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Thank you for the positive assessment.